# Bypass a Javascript infinite loop from Chrome DevTools or similar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have to edit Javascript code of a page that causes an infinite loop.
The problem is that I must edit the source code with an ugly online editor integrated in that page. But due to the infinite loop I can't neither load the editor (I think it uses JS...).

What can I do? Is there a way to bypass only the piece of code that causes the infinite loop (I know where it is)? 
Sadly I can't show you the page cause it's in a restricted area.

Comment: If your editor allows editing without having javascript turned on, try turning off javascript in the browser.

Comment: Sadly no, It doesn't allow. It's a really terrible environment...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here in the documentation with the button Stop Current JavaScript Call: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/devtools#stop